# Navbar with css with different background colours

Tags: html, css

I have the following navbar :

```css
nav ul {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 52px;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
  line-height: 52px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  transition: 0.4s ease;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">One</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Two</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Three</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Four</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Five</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Six</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Seven</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I want the background color of rainbow. I mean tab 1 will have violet, tab 2 will have indigo... and so on. I do this by adding class to each **li**. I can also do this by adding id to each **li**. Isn't there a faster way? **CSS only**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **nth-of-type()** selector

```css
nav ul {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 52px;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
  line-height: 52px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
li:hover {
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}
li:nth-of-type(1):hover {
  background-color: violet;
}
li:nth-of-type(2):hover {
  background-color: indigo;
}
li:nth-of-type(3):hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
li:nth-of-type(4):hover {
  background-color: green;
}
li:nth-of-type(5):hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
li:nth-of-type(6):hover {
  background-color: orange;
}
li:nth-of-type(7):hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">One</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Two</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Three</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Four</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Five</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Six</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Seven</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**BONUS**

Just a suggestion, don't use long selectors like `nav ul li a`. You know that you have one navbar element, in that only one `a` tag. So just cut it short and use `nav a` and so forth ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use:

```
nav > ul > li:nth-child(1){
   background: yellow;
}
nav > ul > li:nth-child(2){
   background: red;      
}
//etc...
```